# How to resolve TransientPropertyValueException in one to one association without using Cascading types?[SOLVED]

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa, associations

I have a Student entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
 
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="dept_id")
  private Department department;
}
```

and a Department Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="department")
public class Department{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
 
  @Column(unique=true)
  private String departmentName;
}
```

Before I save students, I have saved couple of Departments in the the MySQL database. In the Add Student form, I select Department from the dropdown which are fetched from Database. Now when I am about to save Student, following exception occurs:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

By searching on internet, I found that adding CascadeType.ALL resolves the problem. But I don't want the department be saved along with Student when saving Student, because that department is already in the database. Again, CascadeType.ALL tries the existing department to save in the "department" table but fails due to unique deparmentName attribute. Also, I don't want associated department to be removed when I remove any Student.
Please advise. All I want is to make a query where all students will be returned as list and each student object will consist the associated department information also.
Thanks in advance!

*** [SOLVED] The problem is solved actually. Department id was null when passing the department object to Student.***

Comment: This error means you haven't saved the `department` entity in the database before assigning it to the `Student` entity. A typical mistake that can cause this is the `id` field is null somehow. Please, post the logic that actually assigns departments to students and how it saves.

Comment: @AbrahamCiokler You are absolutely right. The Department id was null when passing the department object to Student. Problem solved!. Thanks a lot my friend!

Answer (score 0):

This error means you haven't saved the department entity in the database before assigning it to the Student entity. A typical mistake that can cause this is the id field is null somehow.